# simpleJdbcTemplate multiple row fetch

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, dao, spring-jdbc

I'm using **SimpleJdbcTemplate** to fetch a list of records from a database. Each record corresponds to a data model object. I have searched in the internet a lot but I still
can't figure out how to fetch multiple rows from a database using **generic row mapper**.

Say I need to fetch a **list of objects** of type SampleObj.

How will I define the parameterized row mapper? How will I get the list of the SampleObj type objects?

Whenever I try creating a row mapper, the return type from the row mapper is always detected as a single object rather than a list. Please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The RowMapper [maps one row](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html#mapRow%28java.sql.ResultSet,%20int%29). When you [execute a query](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcTemplate.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper,%20java.lang.Object...%29), every row returned is mapped, and you get a List back. Just try it, and it'll work the way you want. There are examples of doing so throughout the [JDBC chapter of the Spring reference guide](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html).

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I have tried various things till now. but now it worked. I was using queryForList to get the list of objects. But it was returning list of Maps. It worked when I used query().